# how to remove the div permenently from the website?

Tags: windows

I wonder you could help me to remove the div from my website below is the reference.

```
<div style="text-align: center; font-size: smaller; clear: both;">Powered by <a href="http://www.joomultra.com" target="_blank" rel="follow">JU Contact</a></div>
```

There is any way to delete this div?

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there is any way to delete this div?

You are using the free version of a [JoomlaUltra](http://www.joomultra.com/) template.

> You need to purchase paid version to remove this copyright text.

Source [Powered by JU Contact](http://www.joomultra.com/forums/ju-contact-lite/1159-powered-by-ju-contact.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () { 
          $('div').css('display', function () {
             if ($(this).css('clear') == 'both')
                 return 'none'
          });
       });
    </script>

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That won't work. The `div` is added by JU Contact "on the fly" as the page is rendered because he is using the free version of the template. See my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Saw, your answer...This will work.

Comment: Like you said, only if there is a single `div`. That is unlikely.

Comment: @DavidPostill I added a jquery solution that is dependent on the `clear: both` attribute and runs after page load. BTW, How do I insert tab spaces in the answer?

Comment: Add extra 4 spaces at the start of each line for each tab? Your code formatting is completely messed up. Wait and I will fix it.

Comment: Done. Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)